# Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[0].firstChild.wrap is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need quick help with this. I am trying to wrap first node of label with `<span></span>` but it gives error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[0].firstChild.wrap is not a function`

```
$('.lbl')[0].firstChild.wrap('<span></span>');
```

However If I try just following its selects but its has issue with `.wrap`

```
$('.lbl')[0].firstChild
```

Following is the **HTML**

```
<label class="lbl">
some text
<input type="text">
</label>
<label class="lbl">
some text
<input type="text">
</label>
<label class="lbl">
some text
<input type="text">
</label>
<label class="lbl">
some text
<input type="text">
</label>
```

Thanks

Comment: `wrap` is a jQuery function but you use it on a plain DOM object.

Comment: @Xufox thanks any quick work around?

Comment: a quick look in jQuery api would have foind numerous ways to define first element

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers, you did the same thing, trying to access a jQuery method on the actual DOM element. Take the `[0]` off, but I belive OP is trying to wrap the textNode for instance `some text`, which that wouldnt work on

Comment: @AamirShahzad You know you can convert any DOM object to a jQuery object by wrapping it in `$(`…`)`, right?

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers you are doing same thing ...using jQuery method on dom node

Comment: `$('.lbl').first().wrap('<span></span>');` as @charlietfl, mentionned, or by combining many other jquery function like `find` and `children`

Comment: @Xufox thanks I got it. That was silly of me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are wanting to wrap the text node, you need to wrap the whole node in `$()` in order to use jQuery methods

```js
$($('.lbl')[0].firstChild).wrap('<span></span>');
```

```css
span{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="lbl">
some text
<input type="text">
</label>
<label class="lbl">
some text
<input type="text">
</label>
<label class="lbl">
some text
<input type="text">
</label>
<label class="lbl">
some text
<input type="text">
</label>
```